# Infinite loop with v-for in vuetify v-window

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have a problem with vuetify@3.5.3 v-window. I am using v-window and v-tabs together.It is working but Sometimes it fails to display window item without showing any error.

When I run the code bellow it seems to be into an infinite loop.

```js
<template>
  <v-tabs v-model="tabs">
    <v-tab :value="1">tab 1</v-tab>
    <v-tab :value="2">tab 2</v-tab>
    <v-tab :value="3">tab 3</v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
  <v-window v-model="tabs">
    <v-window-item v-for="i in 3" :key="i" :value="i"
      >Window {{ i }}
      {{ console.log(i) }}
    </v-window-item>
  </v-window>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
//
import { ref } from "vue";
const tabs = ref(1);
</script>
```

Would appreciate any form of help, thank you in advance

Comment: What leads you to believe it's in an infinite loop?  The code seems to work fine in [Vuetify Play](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9kUFugzAQRa8ymlUiFRAhXZSSSD1FF3UXlJjIqrEt2xBViLt3jCFik6yYP/955mN/jehsk30Ykw49xxIrzzsja8/PTAFUQ+LrHwdD0ukLlyeGQTKczdWGcqhlz8nMyQmNvMpm5wF2WLDDc6xYsGKLLbVb492Euujbk4ARSAT9F1GttsQIEApoPJS//C/oUK5rScTDAOfPOH0cQcA0hW+jldOSp1Jfd2JPzWURxdpsukeNPZJVtrlYkq6xwniQtbqG0BQZHPe9mU+KzmjrYQTLW5igtboDhvRADN+DH0J4mF/mFJhdvqd+lcWhNAKnFyzSY5q/YShe0yN+/wOmSJvz)